Как передать результат функции (переменную) из одной функции в другую, не объявляя её глобальной в Python
Пишу бота Telegram на TelegramBotApi(telebot). Есть функция func1(callback), в которой происходит подключение к БД, получение списка пользователей и запись в переменную. Также в этой функции происходит вывод кнопок по данным, полученным из бд.
def func1(callback):
    con = fdb.connect(dsn=f'{ip}/4122:{path_to_bd}/MAIN.GDB',
                      user='SYSDBA', password='masterkey', charset='utf8')
    cur = con.cursor()
    nameuser = (f"SELECT ID,NAME FROM \"USER\" WHERE ID = {id_user};")
    cur.execute(nameuser)
    nameuser = cur.fetchone()
    ...
    return nameuser

И хочу передать значение переменной nameuser в следующую функцию, идущую после этой.
Как я могу передать эту переменную в func2(callback) ?
К примеру если попытаться вызвать в func2 переменную таким способом:
def func2(callback):
    nameuser = func1()
    ...

То будет выдавать ошибку, что пропущен один аргумент.
Научите правильно передавать значение переменной, не объявляя переменную в global.
P.S. в Python только начинаю разбираться, тапками не кидаться.

Почему Вы, вызывая func1 изнутри func2, не передаете callback в func1? Оно же на это и ругается.

@AlexeyTrukhanov если передавать callback при вызове func1 из func2, то будет ругаться на func1.data, т.к. существует еще @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def func3(message):
if message.data == 'zapuskfunc2':
func2(message)

Ну, хорошо, а если сначала (до вызова func2) получаем результат из func1 и передаем его вторым аргументом в func2, вместе с колбэком, типа - func2(callback, nameuser)?

И, да, лучше, конечно о существовании func3 упомянуть в самом вопросе, а то непонятно почему Вы колбэк в func1 не передаете.

Кажется, что Ваше решение почти правильное, только надо передать callback при вызове func1(), именно об этом и говорит ошибка о пропущенном аргументе.
def func2(callback):
    nameuser = func1(callback)
    ...

